# Accessing elements in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array:

```
 array = [{key: "6S", values: { 3: [{Id: "1234a"}, {Id: "1234b"}]}},

         {key: "7S", values: { 5: [{Id: "1534a"}], 4: [{Id:"1534a"}]}}]
```

I want to map "3", "5" and "4" (that are actually keys from another list inside the big list) from the values...something like this

```
array.map(function(d)
        {  return d.values."key";}));
```

In order to access the values 3, 5 and 4 I can use a for loop. However, there is a way to access values directly?

Comment: Does ```Object.keys()``` work?

Comment: `Object.keys(d.values)`

Comment: what do you mean by _I want to map "3", "5" and "4"_ ? do you want a separate array/object for them ?

Comment: @GeorgeBailey to create a list with this 3 elements... I want to use this elements as domain of the axis. Object.keys(d.values) return only the elements from the last object of the list.

Comment: @CatalinVasilescu What is your expected output exactly?

Comment: @epascarello Object.keys(d.values) works well only the array contains a single list with objects..For example, in the array from above they Object.keys(d.values) will return "5" and "4"..without 3

Comment: Yes, but you are mapping the outside array.... so than you just do a concat....

Comment: @Eddie ["3", "5" ,"4"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object.keys()` will return an array of the keys of an object. Then you can use `concat()` to concatenate them.

```js
array = [{key: "6S", values: { 3: [{Id: "1234a"}, {Id: "1234b"}]}},
         {key: "7S", values: { 5: [{Id: "1534a"}], 4: [{Id:"1534a"}]}}];
var result = [].concat(...array.map(d => Object.keys(d.values)));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: lol, I just typed `[].concat(...array.map(d => Object.keys(d.values)))` into my console to verify it worked before posting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Object.keys gives you array and as a result in map, you get something like

```
[[3],[4,5]]
```

You can flatten the return array to single array like

```
array.join(',').split(',');
```

```js
var array = [{
        key: "6S",
        values: {
            3: [{
                Id: "1234a"
            }, {
                Id: "1234b"
            }]
        }
    },

    {
        key: "7S",
        values: {
            5: [{
                Id: "1534a"
            }],
            4: [{
                Id: "1534a"
            }]
        }
    }
];

 var newArray = array.map(o=>  Object.keys(o.values))
 
 console.log(newArray.join(',').split(','))
```